# PHP parallel in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, parallel-processing

I would like to run parallel in CodeIgniter, but do not know, how to pass `$this` into parallel closure. I need to call function from model in this closure.

```
class ClassName extends Public_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();   
        
        $this->load->model('some_model', 'model');
    }

    public function parallelFunction(){
         $params = ['param1' => 'value1'];
         $runtime1 = new \parallel\Runtime();
         $runtime1->run(function(){
              $this->model->initFunction($params));
         });
    }
}
```

It throws error:
PHP Fatal error: **Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context**

Comment: hpoe this helps: [Creating Ancillary Classes](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/ancillary_classes.html?highlight=construct#creating-ancillary-classes): "In some cases you may want to develop classes that exist apart from your controllers but have the ability to utilize all of CodeIgniter’s resources. This is easily possible as you’ll see."

Comment: Thank you, but if I use this and pass $CI into closure, I will get this error: illegal parameter (Cron) passed to task at argument 1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's exactly what it's stated. You try to use `$this` but you are not in an object oriented context. I guess you call your functions outside any object class method or your class method is static.

Comment: Nope, it is in Controller Class, I will edit the code for better understanding